# How to download precipitation data using rnoaa

Tags: r, rnoaa

I am new to the 'rnoaa' R package. I am wondering how do I find stationsid names to identify stations. I am interested in downloading hourly or daily precipitation data from 2011 to 2020 from the Prince William Sound Alaska area. I looked here: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search but it seems to have data only up to 2014. Could someone give me a hint on what rnoaa function to use to download the desired rainfall data?
I read that the following rnoaa function:

```
cpc_prcp(date = "1998-04-23", drop_undefined = TRUE)
```

However, I don't know what to include inside the function to get the data that I am looking for and also the range of dates (2011 to 2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this workflow:

An internet search gives the latitude and longitude for Prince William Sound Alaska area.

```r
library(rnoaa)

# create a data frame for Prince William latitude and longitude
lat_lon_df <- data.frame(id = "pw",
                         lat = 60.690545,
                         lon = -147.097055)

# find 10 closest monitors to  Prince William
mon_near_pw <- 
  meteo_nearby_stations(
  lat_lon_df = lat_lon_df,
  lat_colname = "lat",
  lon_colname = "lon",
  var = "PRCP",
  year_min = 2011,
  year_max = 2020,
  limit = 10,
)


mon_near_pw
#> $pw
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    id          name                      latitude longitude distance
#>    <chr>       <chr>                        <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 USC00501240 CANNERY CREEK                 61.0     -148.     42.9
#>  2 USC00509747 WALLY NOERENBERG HATCHERY     60.8     -148.     55.1
#>  3 USS0048L06S Esther Island                 60.8     -148.     55.3
#>  4 USC00505604 MAIN BAY                      60.5     -148.     57.6
#>  5 USS0046M04S Sugarloaf Mtn                 61.1     -146.     61.1
#>  6 USC00509687 VALDEZ                        61.1     -146.     62.4
#>  7 USW00026442 VALDEZ WSO                    61.1     -146.     63.4
#>  8 US1AKVC0005 VALDEZ 3.6 ENE                61.1     -146.     66.3
#>  9 USC00509685 VALDEZ AIRPORT                61.1     -146.     67.3
#> 10 USC00502179 CORDOVA WWTP                  60.5     -146.     74.0

# extract precipitation data for the first location
pw_prcp_dat <- 
  meteo_pull_monitors(
  monitors = mon_near_pw$pw$id[1],
  date_min = "2011-01-01",
  date_max = "2020-12-31",
  var = "PRCP"
)

head(pw_prcp_dat)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   id          date        prcp
#>   <chr>       <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 USC00501240 2011-01-01   704
#> 2 USC00501240 2011-01-02   742
#> 3 USC00501240 2011-01-03   211
#> 4 USC00501240 2011-01-04   307
#> 5 USC00501240 2011-01-05   104
#> 6 USC00501240 2011-01-06     0

# out of curiosity have plotted monthly summary of precipitation.
# For metadata see: https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/readme.txt
# PRCP = Precipitation (tenths of mm)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

pw_prcp_dat %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date),
         month = month(date)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(prcp = sum(prcp, na.rm = TRUE) / 10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(month), prcp))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(~year)+
  labs(y = "Precipitation [mm]",
       x = "Month")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @Peter-- This is great, Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know what the units are for prcp? Should it be inches or mm?

Comment: That's awesome!!!! I have been on this for hours and you solved it in a few minutes. The function that you used for precipitation could be used as well for water temperature in Prince William Sound or is a total different function and package?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with noaa data; I don't know  about water temperature, I've only explored noaa for UK weather data. You can find out what variables are available from the metadata link and reading up on the functions and trying out the examples in the package documentation should help.

Comment: Thanks again Peter, I up voted your answer. Really appreciate your help.